# Import SQL Server database from large script

Tags: sql-server

Opening large sql script generated by SQL Server publisher cant be open in management studio, returning error about not enough available storage to open it.

Is there some other way to import db from large script ? (command line maybe)

Comment: What does the script do as if it imports data then you should be able to use some ETL tool within your database (I.E., SSIS for SQL Server 2005/2008)

Comment: Please post the actual error message you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something you have to edit? If so, you may want to open it in Notepad++ or TextPad or Editplus.

Here are some options I can think of:

- Use the batch separator `GO` between sets of commands. The reason for this is that without the GO, SSMS is trying to execute the entire script as a single command. This puts a heavier load on memory requirements than multiple batches would.
- To run the script, you can use [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) from the command line.
- Also, for large scripts that load data, you may want to ensure that you have `COMMIT` commands in the script (where appropriate).
- Consider splitting your script into multiple scripts.
- If you split into multiple files and build the `SQLCMD` command line syntax, you can run all scripts from a single batch file fairly quickly.

Comment: lol my link had a reference to the future removal of osql. +1

Comment: This time I've mage Backup of target db and Restore on my machine/server with replace option and it went well. I'll take I look at what you proposed also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [OSql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) tool?